# Javascript document.querySelectorAll() is not working for Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying build a simple web scraping tool. The data I am trying scrape has a infinite scroll. Following are functions I am using:

```
async function scrapeInfiniteScrollItems(page,extractItems,itemTargetCount,scrollDelay = 1000) {
    let items = [];
    try {
      let previousHeight;
      while (items.length < itemTargetCount) {
        items = await page.evaluate(extractItems);
        previousHeight = await page.evaluate('document.body.scrollHeight');
        await page.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
        await page.waitForFunction(`document.body.scrollHeight > ${previousHeight}`);
        await page.waitFor(scrollDelay);
      }
    } catch(e) { console.log(e)}
    return items; ---> items.length is Always 42, It should be 482
}
```

Following is my **extractItems** function:

```
function extractItems(){
    postLinksArray = [];
    let postsArray = document.querySelectorAll('.v1Nh3'); -->class name
    console.log(postsArray.length);
    for(var post of postsArray){
        let postLink = post.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href');
        postLinksArray.push(postLink);  
    }
    return postLinksArray;
}
```

As you can see its pretty straight forward, I am using the puppeteer library. After the scrapeInfiniteScrollItems function returns. The length of the items array is always 42. It should be 482. Can you someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are overwriting the `items` array every time the loop runs with this line: `items = await page.evaluate(extractItems)`. If you want all of the items to be in the array, either use `.push` like this:

```
let newItems = await page.evaluate(extractItems);
items.push(newItems);
```

or try something more functional like this:

```
let newItems = await page.evaluate(extractItems);
items = [...items, newItems];
```

That way all of the items should be present in the array when you go to return it.

Comment: No, Its still 42

Comment: waiting for function failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded i got that error as well

Comment: Hmm... then it might be that your loop is only running once. Can you insert a `console.log` statement in the loop and see how many times it prints? If it's still returning only 42, then I would need to look at the page you're trying to scrape to see how its behaving

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem with puppeteer/my expression `page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelectorAll()}` code.  It's only returning the first 25 items when there's supposed to be ~1000 at the end of the 'infinite scroll'.  In the page that I'm trying to scrape all these items from, I know that there are fetch requests in the network tab of the developer tools being performed at various urls every time you scroll to the max scroll height of the page; however, the initial url does not change.  It seems like an issue of `document.querySelectorAll`, though. Not sure how to tackle this as I'm only a few lines of code off (I think) from making this work.  Hope to hear if you figured anything out here!